# How to sort table data from client side according to a specific table data using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sorting, client-side-scripting

Here is my Table data coded in laravel. I just want to sort data as per Issue date. I have to do it from client end and can not do it from controller for some reason. I would like to have some suggestion or demo code of javascript. Thanks in advance.

```
 <table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>PR ID</th>
        <th>PR Type</th>
        <th>Issue Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php 
         $j=1;
         $checker = 1;
         $checker2 = 0;
         if($current > 1){
            $checker = $current*2;
            $checker2 = ($current*2)+50;
         }else if( $quot_count = 1 && $current = 1){
            $checker2 = 2;
         }else if( $quot_count = 2 && $current = 1){
            $checker2 = 50;
         }else{
            $checker2 = ($current*2)+2;
         }?>
         @for($i= $checker; $i < $checker+50; $i++ )
            @if(isset($quotations->$i->qr_details->pr_id))
         <tr>
            <td>{{ $j++ }}</td>
            <td class="prId" id=""><a style="cursor: pointer;" class="pr-modal" rel="{{$i}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$i}}">{{ $quotations->$i->qr_details->pr_id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $quotations->$i->qr_details->pr_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $quotations->$i->qr_dates->start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $quotations->$i->qr_dates->end_date }}</td>
         </tr>
         @endif
         @endfor
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: use `sortBy` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby)

Comment: The problem is already solved by rewriting the controller function.Thanks for your response.